# How to create and modify columns efficiently in a function?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, iteration, environment

I have a dataframe where I'd like to add multiple new columns based on existing variables. All of these columns I want to create/modify in the same way. For a simple example let's say I want to create new columns that add a constant to the values in existing columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

# make a little dataframe
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 v2 = c("good","bad","ugly","good","bad"))

### here's what we want to do in the function, but lets do it outside first
df$v3 <- df$v1 + 2

# and we end up with df, including v3
df <- select(.data = df, -v3)
df
```

In my actual case it's a bit more complicated than that and includes multiple steps beyond just adding, so I'd like to do this iteratively. Given how slow loops are in R, I'm trying to do this in a function, like so:

```
# now we want to add 3 variables, v3, v4, v5
addv <- function(newv, adder){
  print("inside function")
  df[newv] <- df$v1 + adder
  return(df)
}
```

I could just keep calling the function over and over to get this result:

```
# call it to see if it works
df <- addv(newv = "v3", adder = 2)
df

# we could do it multiple times like this
df <- addv(newv = "v3", adder = 2)
df <- addv(newv = "v4", adder = 3)

# but we want a way of calling it and returning just df
```

This, though, is very, very slow in my data (which will have roughly 10s of millions of observations and 30-40 variables initially before adding maybe 20 new columns in this function).

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I usually use functions with an apply function, but I don't think that quite works in this example where I want it to return a dataframe (and I don't want to have to `bind_rows` or something).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the function showed, it may be vectorized instead of a `loop`

```
nm1 <- c("v3", "v4")
val <- c(2, 3)
df[nm1] <- df$v1 + rep(c(2, 3), each = nrow(df))
```

Or just use a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(nm1)) df <- addv(new = nm1[i], adder = val[i])
```

-output

```
> df
  v1   v2 v3 v4
1  1 good  3  4
2  2  bad  4  5
3  3 ugly  5  6
4  4 good  6  7
5  5  bad  7  8
```

---

Or using `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2_dfc(nm1, val, ~ df %>%
      transmute(!!.x := v1 + .y)) %>% 
      bind_cols(df, .)
```

Comment: My understand is the for loop would be really slow, hence the function attempt -- do you think `map` is faster?

Comment: @dmcd Function is just a convenient wrapper to reuse.  It wouldn't have much effect on the efficiency.  As we are creating multiple columns, either `map` or simply do `df[nm1] <- df$v1 + rep(c(2, 3), each = nrow(df))`